# Terraform local-exec failing on authenticating git push

Tags: git, azure-devops, terraform

Terraform local-exec provider is used for running a batch script.
In this bash script I'm trying to perform serious of git operations and perform a git push.

I have a terraform.tfvars file as given below

```
 repo_list = ["Dev1-Repo1","Dev2-Repo2","Dev3_Repo3"]
```

I'm using terraform code to provision these repos and use a local-exec to run the bash script against each of this repos

But the problem is that **while git pushing the prompt is coming to provide the PAT token and when i provide the PAT the git pushing will happen against one repo and other two get failed becuase of below issue**

```
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/_git/Dev1-Repo1/'
```

How we usually authenticate the git operations through Terraform ?

The null resource code is given below

```
resource "null_resource" "mytest" {
  for_each = toset(var.resource_list)


    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sh test.sh ${each.value}"
 }
}
```

Comment: What is the code with the local-exec?

Comment: Post the terraform code and the script code (scrub off private things).

Comment: Did you try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-a-pat ?